# Windows Form Application - C# Getting User Input

Tags: c#, programming-languages, windows-forms-designer

I'm using C# to make a Windows Form Application. I have a form with 4 labels, 4 textboxes, and 3 buttons. The only textbox that can have anything entered inside of it is the 1 first box, the rest have TapStop = false. I want the user to be able to enter a bunch of numbers in that 1st textbox and I want those numbers to get added to get the average and total. I already have a button that the user can push once they enter something. What I'm trying to do it similar to a calculator. User enters 1 number, then another, then another so on. I want to take all of those numbers and get the total, the amount of numbers they entered, and the average. I'm having trouble getting all of those numbers ready to be calculated.  I created an event handler for the Add button and declared variables for the average and total. I'm having trouble with these 2 things:

1- I'm not sure how to get the input every time the user enters something.

2- I'm not sure how to convert the numbers the user enters since default is string in text boxes.

Tried to be as specific as I could since I don't have any code besides the event handler I made and the variables I declared because I'm not sure what to do next.

Any suggestions for these 2 things? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- I'm not sure how to get the input every time the user enters something.

If you want to update your values based on user input without pushing the button you can use the TextChanged event, where to find it? just double click on the textbox in the designer, then everytime the user change the text in this textbox this event will fire.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

> 2- I'm not sure how to convert the numbers the user enters since default is string in text boxes.

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

EDIT

so based on your comment, here is my solution.

```
    //The entered values will be stored as List of integars.
    List<int> enteredValues = new List<int>();

    //The button will store each value in the List of integers.
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value;

        if(int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out value))
        {
            enteredValues.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            //Show error message here.
        }
    }

    //This button will calculate the sum of entered values.
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalValues = 0;
        foreach(int val in enteredValues)
        {
            totalValues += val;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I need to use the button so I can't remove it. What I'm trying to do it similar to a calculator. User enters 1 number, then another, then another so on. I want to take all of those numbers and get the total, the amount of numbers they entered, and the average. I'm having trouble getting all of those numbers ready to be calculated.

Comment: @rythm500 you need to be more specific in your question (very specific) your comments are very different to what you original wrote

Comment: Sorry still new on stack, updated the question to be more specific!

Comment: I'm trying to follow your sample code and I had a question about the if statement. Can you please explain why you need the if statement? Because I'm not sure what to put inside of the else since I can't add anything besides the 4 labels, 4 text boxes, and 3 buttons I already have. Is there another way to just save the numbers can do calculations with them without the if statement?

Comment: The return value of "Int32.TryParse" indicates whether the operation succeeded. For more info, you can refer to [Int32.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The if statement is there just to make sure the user input is integer because If it’s not integer the program will break down, about what to put in “else” you can do like     MassageBox.show(“This field takes only numbers, Please correct your input.”)